# Trigger a Local Notification every day at particular time even when the app is closed

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

**I have to display a notification every day at particular time *(say 7.00am)* to the users from my app even when my app was not running.(closed)**

*As the content of the notification will be user specific, I cant use (GCM)push*

I have gone through a lot of tutorials and answers but I cant able to display notification when the app is closed (not running).

**Edit: Using the below code I'm able to Create a Notification while my app is running, if I close my app notifications are showing up**

**Here is my main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button setAlarm;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.set_alarm);
    setAlarm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NotificationEventReceiver.setupAlarm(getApplicationContext());
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    setIntent(intent);
}
}
```

here when I click the set Alarm button my `NotificationEventReciver` will call

```
public class NotificationEventReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
private static final String ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE = "ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE";
private static final String ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION = "ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION";


public static void setupAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, getTriggerAt(new Date()), 2 * 60 * 1000, alarmIntent);

}
private static long getTriggerAt(Date now) {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 10);
    System.err.println(now.getTime()+"----->"+ calendar.getTimeInMillis());
    return calendar.getTimeInMillis();
}

public static void cancelAlarm(Context context) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = getStartPendingIntent(context);
    alarmManager.cancel(alarmIntent);
}


private static PendingIntent getStartPendingIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START_NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

public static PendingIntent getDeleteIntent(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationEventReceiver.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_DELETE_NOTIFICATION);
    return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent serviceIntent =  NotificationIntentService.createIntentStartNotificationService(context);
    if (serviceIntent != null) {
        System.err.println("onReceive inside not null");
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, serviceIntent);
    }
}
}
```

My service class which will run when alarm get off.

```
public class NotificationIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private static final String ACTION_START = "ACTION_START";
private static final String ACTION_DELETE = "ACTION_DELETE";

public NotificationIntentService() {
    super(NotificationIntentService.class.getSimpleName());
}

public static Intent createIntentStartNotificationService(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationIntentService.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_START);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    System.err.println("onHandleIntent, started handling a notification event");
    try {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (ACTION_START.equals(action)) {
            System.err.println("enters the loop ACTION_START");
            processStartNotification();
        }
    } finally {
        WakefulBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}


private void processStartNotification() {
    // Do something. For example, fetch fresh data from backend to create a rich notification?
    System.err.println("inside the notify method");
    Intent mainIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, NOTIFICATION_ID, mainIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    final NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    builder.setContentTitle("Scheduled Notification")
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent))
            .setContentText("This notification has been triggered by Notification Service")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    final NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
}
}
```

Comment: You can push user specifi data via gcm. Have the gcm reg id association with ur user or device and send it directly to the users phone..

Comment: you need to use a combination on Alarm Manager, Pending Intent and Broadcast Receiver.

Comment: @Aradhna please go through the code fully! I'm exactly using all the three and able to create a notification but! if my app is closed my notification is not working!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this in your `setUpAlarm` method-

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) cont
                        .getSystemService(cont.ALARM_SERVICE);

 Intent intent = new Intent(cont, MyReceiver.class);    
intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER); 

boolean isWorking = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, 1001, 

    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
    if (isWorking) { 
    // first cancel previous alarm 
    Intent intent = new Intent(cont, MyReceiver.class);// the same as up 
    intent.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER);// the same as up 
    PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(cont, 1001, 
    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);// the same as up 
    am.cancel(pI);// important 
    pI.cancel();// important 
    } else { 
    Intent intent1 = new Intent(cont, MyReceiver.class); 
    intent1.setAction(MyReceiver.ACTION_ALARM_RECEIVER); 
    
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent 
    .getBroadcast(cont, 0, intent1, 
    PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); 
    AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) cont 
    .getSystemService(cont.ALARM_SERVICE); 
    
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, 
    calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 
    AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent); 
    }
```

Comment: I changed the repeate time to 2 min for testing!

Comment: It is always going inside isWorking true loop! it is not going to else part

Comment: Yes it will and that is what you have to check. The else part will run only the first time the app is launched

Comment: So do you have this issue, when u turn on the switch(for Notifications) you will get the notification immediately irrespective of time, after first time!

Comment: No. There is no need for a switch. What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: actually, in my app there is an option to turn on/off notifications! when I on the switch and the set time is in the past, notification is displaying immediately!

Comment: That is because when the switch is off, you are not deleting your alarm in the correct manner and hence it is being stored.

Comment: Can you help me with set time, getTriggerAt is not setting the time properly